VueJs3 pinia store not axios posting to correct api url from environment file
I have an .env file that works locally that has the following set: (Same host, different ports)
VUE_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:5038
VUE_APP_UI_URL=http://localhost:8080

On hosting service: (I am using Render)
VUE_APP_API_URL=https://my-app-ui.onrender.com
VUE_APP_UI_URL=https://my-app-api.onrender.com

But when I try to host this, I get the following error:
https://my-app-ui.onrender.com/my-app-api.onrender.com/user/exists/username/null 404 (Not Found)
So something is funky with the environment urls.
Example Store:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { useUserStore } from '@/stores';
import axios from 'axios';

const baseUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL + "/gift";

export const useGiftStore = defineStore({
    id: 'gift',
    state: () => ({
        gifts: null
    }),
    actions: {
        async create(obj) {
            let payload = obj;
            if (!obj.userId) {
                const userStore = useUserStore();
                payload.userId = userStore.user._id;
            }
            try {
                let gift = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}`, payload);
                return gift.data;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error: ", error);               
            }
        },
    }
});


Do you use Nuxt3? Then you can use $fetch without the need for axios. Also prefer using import.meta.env. Feel free to build locally for debugging purposes, to see if you can replicate the issue. Try to host it on another platform too (depending if you use SSR or not). Do you have any errors in your logs or in the console while in production? Did you console.log the value of process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL while in production? Did you add the HOST value?

Thank you for all the tips on things to try! I will post what I find

Okay so I don't use Nuxt, but I redeployed and it worked fine

Out of curiosity, why do you use Render and not Netlify/Vercel/Cloudflare if you have no use for SSR?

I am just really learning about these services. What's wrong with using Render? @kissu

Idk, it's not the big names for SPAs in general. You have more integrations and more benefits with the other ones IMO. Render is kinda the latest underdog that came to help after the downfall of Heroku's pricing. But Render is IMO only for SSR apps with a 24/7 running Node. At the end of the day, you can publish your static app anywhere because there are no specific limits to such apps. Just an unusual way to deploy FE apps but if it's works for you then it's cool!

No that's good to know! I'm just getting off the ground with my first personal project since joining the workforce 7 years ago, so I'm happy to try other things. Thanks for the tip! @kissu
